# plupload force landscape mode

Tags: landscape, plupload

I'd like to force users to upload only landscape files using plupload.

I've not seen any filters (only for files type) able to do that.

Here is my code :

```
    var initUploader = function () {
    $("#uploader").pluploadQueue({
        // General settings
        runtimes : 'html5,gears,flash,silverlight,browserplus',
        url : 'http://xxx',
        max_file_size : '10mb',
        chunk_size : '1mb',
        unique_names : true,

        // Resize images on clientside if we can
        resize : {width : 320, height : 240, quality : 90},

        // Specify what files to browse for
        filters : [
            {title : "Image files", extensions : "jpg,gif,png"}
        ],

        // Flash settings
        flash_swf_url : '/js/plupload/js/plupload.flash.swf',

        // Silverlight settings
        silverlight_xap_url : '/js/plupload/js/plupload.silverlight.xap',

        // send extra parameters :
        multipart_params : {
            'title': 'Picture title',
            'pictureCategory': 'Banniere',
            'vigneronID': $('#vigneron_id').val()
        },
        init: {
            FilesAdded: function (up, files) {
                alert('Selected files: ' + files.length);
            },
            UploadComplete: function (up, files) {
                // destroy the uploader and init a new one
                up.destroy();
                initUploader();
            }
        }
    });
};
```

I wander if in the init section, where I alert file length, I am able to access width / height properties in order to detect file orientation and then allow or not to add it to the queue.

plupload File API (http://www.plupload.com/plupload/docs/api/index.html#class_plupload.File.html) doesn't seem to offer these properties !

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: AFAIK, you can't do that through the API as the behavior is really low level and runtime specific. See for example the implementation of scaling for html5 runtime https://github.com/moxiecode/plupload/blob/1.x/src/javascript/plupload.html5.js#L140

Comment: Thanks for link, as I don't want to modify different runtimes, I'll do it server-side. I was trying to minimize bandwidth by doing it client-side !